# Google Maps API setLabelColor

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to set the label colour, but I do not think setLabelColor() is a built-in function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(amenities[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        for (j = 0; j < gmarkers.length; j++) {
            gmarkers[j].setIcon(blackCircle); //resets default icon when another is clicked
            gmarkers[j].setLabelColor('white');
        }
        marker.setIcon(whiteCircle); //Sets clicked icon
        marker.setLabelColor('black');
    }
})(marker, i));
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: gmarkers[j].setLabelColor is not a function
```

I know setLabel() is a function, but I only want to change the colour, the label itself is fine as it is?!

Comment: Are you sure `gmarkers` has that marker? I don't think the issue is with this portion of your code.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. If I remove both `gmarkers[j].setLabelColor('white');` and `marker.setLabelColor('black');` lines, the code works fine.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle including full code then?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5aa9jtax/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setLabel`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) to set the label to a [MarkerLabel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerLabel) object

To track the label so you can keep it the same, one option is to save it in a custom property of the marker (example below uses ._labelText).

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(amenities[i][1], amenities[i][2]),
  map: map,
  icon: blackCircle, //Sets default icon
  zIndex: -100,
  label: {
    text: "" + amenities[i][3],
    color: '#EDEBDD'
  },
  _labelText: "" + amenities[i][3]
});
gmarkers.push(marker);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(amenities[i][0]);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    for (j = 0; j < gmarkers.length; j++) {
      gmarkers[j].setIcon(blackCircle); //resets default icon when another is clicked
      gmarkers[j].setLabel({
        color: 'white',
        text: gmarkers[j]._labelText
      });
      gmarkers[j].setZIndex(-100);
    }
    this.setIcon(whiteCircle); //Sets clicked icon
    this.setLabel({
      color: 'black',
      text: this._labelText
    });
    this.setZIndex(100);
  }
})(marker, i));
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5aa9jtax/8/)

Comment: Thanks for this, I implemented here:

https://jsfiddle.net/5aa9jtax/3/

But it messes up the numbering system when one is clicked?

Comment: It would have been more useful for you to post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **before** your question was answered.  To fix that you need to keep the information about the markers label available.